Calling controller endpoint with reactJS and populating dropdown
I am interested how I can populate this code and dropdown in last part of it (country part):
                <div class="new-member-wrap">
                <div id="new-member" class="new-member-inner">
                    <h2>Create new client</h2>
                    <ul class="form">
                        <li>
                            <label>Client name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="in-text" />
                        </li>                               
                        <li>
                            <label>Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="in-text" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>City:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="in-text" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Zip/Postal code:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="in-text" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Country:</label>
                                <select>
                                    <option>Select country</option>
                                </select>
                            </select>                               
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn green">Save</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

With this method values?
[HttpGet("GetCountries")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CountryReturnable>>> GetAllCountries() 
{
    try
    {
        var result = await _countryService.GetAllCountriesAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, $"Error retrieving countries: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

I am having a lot of issues and literally can't create any working reactJS code to do job for me. Route is api/Country/GetCountries.
